# Global variable in ionic3

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I try to make a Quizapp with the Ionic-Framework. The app contains some questions, which were stored in a database.

Every round the app generates a random id by the count of stored questions. I want to store the id's in an array, which blocks the last 10 questions. 
For this, I figured out something like a global variable, which is active the whole app lifetime. 
How do I achieve this?

My app uses actually four sites: home, question, a wrong page and a right page. When I change the site, I uses a setRoot(), but I don't want to drag the array through every page (it will be need only on the question-page).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Local storage for temporary data, localStorage.setItem(key, value) and localStorage.getItem(key)

Answer (score 0):

If it should be persistent I suggest you just dump it into [Ionic Storage](https://ionicframework.com/docs/storage/).

Answer (score 0):

```
getArray(){
    return localStorage.ara;
}

setArray(ara){
    localStorage.ara = ara;
}
```

You can use localstorage.. IT is accessible globally on your application . you can such get and set functions in your service. and can use it globally